# I'm having trouble finding the correct first day of the month for a calendar

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my program display a calendar for whatever month I specify, and it shows the correct number of days for each month, but it starts each month on the wrong day most of the time.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class FirstOfMonth 
{
int m;
int y;
int x;

public FirstOfMonth()
{
}

public void setFirstOfMonth(int month, int year)
{
    m = month;
    y = year;

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(y, m, 1);
    x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
}

public double getFirstOfMonth()
{
    return x;
}

}
```

Comment: Remmber is zero based, january is zero and december eleven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason GregorianCalendar defines January as month 0 (see the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29)), so your code needs to compensate for that:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(y, m-1, 1);
```

Highly confusing all that old time and date stuff in Java, luckily with Java 8 there's [JSR-310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).